# Fantasy book about a girl who goes through a portal to another world where her parents once ruled a kingdom

Tags: story-identification, books, isekai

I read this book when I was in middle school, so 2015 or 2016. It started with the main character, a girl, in a computer lab, bored out of her mind. A portal to another world opened up and, very confused, she goes through it and meets a boy.

She eventually goes back to the real world, and is greeted by one of her parents. Not sure if it was the mom or dad who had a odd death; either killed or died from some unexplained disease. Turns out they ruled in the fantasy kingdom. She finds out she has powers and she was born there, but to protect her, they left it all behind.

It's a series. There was also a scene with a boy she knew and they met somewhere icy and cold; they made eye contact. I think she was falling for him, but saw he wasn't into her like before and something had changed him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall anything about the covers of any of these books?

Comment: I think it was some mystical cover with these trees in the background. Most of the covers looked the same just different colors like green, blue

Comment: You should put that in the question.  Comments can vanish.